# Reading a simple .txt file with python, why does this simple code output every line? How does python know it should do that?

Tags: python, python-3.x

New to programming, newer to python ;) trying to learn file operations.
I dont understand how the code below works. what happens when `open()` is called with a for loop and why is this different to another python  function `.read(number_of_elements)` ?

i have a test.txt file which is just numbered from 1) to 10), each on a new line. So a txt file with 10 lines. Why does python show the whole txt file using this for loop? Why does it know to print every line, at each new line? is it because Python converts the .txt into a list and then loops through it?

i have tried doing
`print(f)`
but this returns some information about the test.txt file, and did not print the content of the file like i expected.

python code:

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line)
```

test.txt file:

```
1)
2)
3)
4)
...
```

Comment: I suggest that you have a look at the python docs (https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) you can find information about the methods in the provided link. What python does in open is prepare your file for reading in your case and exposes it's internal reference through 'f', which we can imagine is an object. If you iterate over 'f' python will return every line of the file separated, it knows how to separate the line looking for a special character called new line: '\n'

Comment: The open file is an iterable that returns one line per iteration - Python `lists` and other collections are iterables too. `f.read()` will return the content of the file as a string (probably it is not wise to use it with a very large file).

Comment: thank you gentlemen this cleared things up. <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is it because Python converts the .txt into a list and then loops through it

Effectively, yes. The code can be rewritten as:

```
file = open("test.txt", "r")
for line in file:
    print(line)

file.close()
```

There is a bit of "magic" involved, but basically the `File` object in `file` knows that if it's being iterated on (via `for line in file`), it should give one line per each iteration.

Iterating a file per-line is often what you want to do - so python offers a quick and easy way to do just that. If you want the whole file in a single variable, there's also a method for that.

Comment: Thank you Bro <3 python is so awesome it confuses the foobar out of me. Other than reading the documentation where can i find out about more quirks? just trial and error?

Comment: I would say that those are not "quirks", just the way Python works. I personally learned Python based on what I currently needed (StackOverflow + Google are your friends), but there are plenty of tutorials available. But even today, when I am coding professionally, there is plenty of, as you say it, trial and error. Oftentimes the function you use is documented well (use an IDE, such as Pycharm, as that helps a lot). But sometimes the fastest way is to just try how something behaves and if it still seems weird, just google for it. Chances are, you are not the first to be confused. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The variable `f` is your whole document.

Let's talk about with the `for line in f:`:

By using this line you are looping through each line of the text file. so each time in the loop the value of `line` is your new line of file and when the `print(line)` runs it will print each line for you with a `\n` which means goes to next line.

> You can reach more examples and information using this link: [File
>   in Python](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_open.asp)

Comment: thank you, i knew how the for loop works in python i just didnt know that open() amkes the content iterable for every new line \n. I was confused why the for loop worked and how python assigned the line variable to every  \n

Comment: Aha, I got it. As I mentioned in the 3rd paragraph with printing it appends a new `\n`. You can change it by printing like this: `print(line,end=' ')` . This way it won't print a new line and will print a space instead.

Comment: thats not what i meant, martin answered what i meant above: "There is a bit of "magic" involved, but basically the File object in file knows that if it's being iterated on (via for line in file), it should give one line per each iteration." as i said i didnt know that python function open() will iterate each new line as in it just works so easy with for loops.